# Removing new line and tab in a oracle database table column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is the post regarding  some problem with new line and tab in a oracle database table column

as the problem is that I have to create a column which 
 takes only **keyboard symbols and alphanumerical values** and i am able to get the
null value in the column but not able to get the new line ( ex chr(13),chr(9),chr(10), if i get one of this also, its difficult to get the combination of both)

I have used reg_exp (like and replace ) and also tanslate and repalce dint find any proper solution.

ex

create table Table1(someField varchar2(100) );

insert into Table1 values ( 'hi'|| CHR(10)||'how r u');

insert into Table1 values ( 'hello'|| CHR(13)||'&');

error must not come because we have a value that is 
1)  insert "hi

how r u"- successful  .

2)  insert "hello  &"- successful  .

but while inserting only space (chr(10)/chr(13)/chr(9) or space or tab)

error must come under below insert condition

insert into someTable values (  CHR(10));

insert into someTable values ( ' '|| CHR(10));

insert into someTable values ( ' 
'|| CHR(10)||'    ');

Comment: Welcome to SO!. What do you need to do? do you need a query to discover such characters, an update to remove them, a check to prevent them to  be inserted into your columns, ...? Please try to be more detailed, posting some sample data, desired result anq what you tried so far

Comment: prevent them from  inserting  only (chr(13)|chr(9)|chr(10) and space and tab) into the columns . column must only take (keyboard symbols and alphanumerical values )

Answer (score 1):

One way could be by adding a [check constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) to your table; for example:

```
alter table table1 add constraint table1Check check (
    regexp_replace(somefield, '[' || chr(10) || chr(9) ||chr(13) || ' ]', '') is not null
    )
```

What you have:

```
SQL> insert into Table1 values ( 'hi'|| CHR(10)||'how r u');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into Table1 values ( 'hello'|| CHR(13)||'&');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into Table1 values ( CHR(10));
insert into Table1 values ( CHR(10))
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (ALEK.TABLE1CHECK) violated


SQL> insert into Table1 values ( ' '|| CHR(10));
insert into Table1 values ( ' '|| CHR(10))
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (ALEK.TABLE1CHECK) violated


SQL> insert into Table1 values ( ' '|| CHR(10)||' ');
insert into Table1 values ( ' '|| CHR(10)||' ')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (ALEK.TABLE1CHECK) violated
```

This way you will not be able to insert a value not matching your condition.

Comment: thank you ...but I need a validation or a check to tell that a person or user cant enter ONLY chr(10) or chr(13) or chr(9) or space or tab..if 'abc' is present alone with the CHR(10) then its not a problem... only if he enters (chr(10) or chr(13) or chr(9) or space or tab).

Comment: It's not that different; just edited to show you how to check your condition

Comment: in that case , if some one enter any value and type enter newline (chr(13)/chr(10) then the constraint will trigger. i want a constraint only if empty space in a column like chr(13)/chr(10)  then the constraint must trigger/fire

Comment: It's not clear to me. Please edit the question by adding some sample data and needed result.